# fmincon convergence time

Tags: matlab

I tried fmincon today and I found that it converges really fast. The values that it gives are also kind of perfect. I am not sure how. At the start it takes a big step. I had two parameters initialized at 1 and 1. Suddenly it jumps to have the values changed to 51 and 130. That's a big step. I am not sure if this is a good thing. But I want to know how come fmincon converges so fast and finds the value. Any insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MALTAB's `fmincon` function implements several algorithms. So the speed of convergence will depend on the objective function and type of the constraints. MATLAB will choose automatically the best possible algorithm. In most cases it will be interior-point algorithm. These family of algorithms is known for its fast convergence on really big problems. Most of interior-point algorithms take about 20-60 steps to converge. Bottom line, my answer is yes - this is absolutely normal if `fmincon` converges really fast. If you need more details set `Display` option to `'iter-detailed'` using `optimset` and you will see details for each iterations.